# Convex optimization problem with set number of KKT-points

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ convex and $C^1$, $g:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with all $g_i$ convex, $C^1$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ affine linear and the problem
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} \quad g(x) \le 0, ~h(x) = 0,
$$
i.e. a generic convex problem.

It is well known that this type of convexity is not a constrained qualification, i.e. there can be minimal points that are not KKT-points (i.e. $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = x^2$, $h(x) = 0$). So I think it should be possible to construct a problem of this type with exactly 42 KKT-points. Problem is, that all those are global minima and by convexity, there are then infinitely many global minima. So some of them have to be KKT-points and some of them not. Can anyone provide me with an example of such problem or a proof that such problem can't exist?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the KKT conditions are satisfied at $x_1,x_2$ then these are optimal, hence so is the entire segment $[x_1,x_2]$.

Comment: Do you assume differentiability of the involved functions?

Comment: Should have mentioned that, yes they are

Comment: @copper.hat I know. But are they KKT-points though?